# Should OneToOneField relations show up in both tables in Admin mode? If not, can you force it?

Tags: django, django-models

I've created two classes:

```
Class Transactions
    Account = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class Meta_table(models.Model):
    Identifier = models.OneToOneField(Transaction, primary_key=True, to_field='Account', related_name='transactions')
```

When in admin mode, should I be able to see `Meta_table` in the `Transactions` table view? and vice versa?

If not, how can I write the code so that `Meta_table` show up under `Transactions`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display a field on the changelist page, you need to include it in the [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) option. Since you have a one to one field, it is easy to display the field in both model admins.

```
class Meta_tableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (..., 'identifier')
    list_select_related = ('identifier',)

admin.site.register(Meta_Admin, Meta_tableAdmin)

class TransactionsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('account', 'transactions', ...)
    list_select_related = ('transactions',)

admin.site.register(Transactions, TransactionsAdmin):
```

Here, we are using `transactions` because that is the related name. Since the reverse relation goes from `Transactions` to `Meta_Table`, it might be better to use something like `related_name='metatable'`.

We have used [`list_select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_select_related) to prevent an extra SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks I tried out the code and I see where you are going. I was wondering if there is a way to add the output of the meta_table into transactions.  Meaning each time you click on a transactions, the associated meta_table entry shows up with in the transactions.

Comment: You can include the meta table as an [inline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).